# How to find and add phone number country code if not valid in php

Tags: php

Example for a phone number in Malaysia starting with 01; if I add the country code, it will be +601 or 601.

Without country code: 0123456789; with country code: 60123456789 or +60123456789.

The result I want is `+60123456789` but some users may enter like:

```
123456789
0123456789
60123456789
```

What is the method I need use to get my result like `+60123456789`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [regex pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_regex.asp) with [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to substitute those:

```
$phone = preg_replace('~^(?:0?1|601)~','+601', $phone);
```

See [PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj7AI4CLS6UgIz8vNT6vNDcptahYwVZBncvQyNjE1MzcwpLLAME0Q2Jrgzl6enpc6tZcXKnJGfkKBUWp6fFFqQU5icmpGup1cRr2Vgb2hjVAhZp1ueo66iAt6joKqLZpAnX//w8A) or [regex pattern at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/feZBmi/1) (explanation on right side).

For further regex info see this nice [Stackoverflow Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).